# TorchScript model output is not the same as Pytorch model output

Tags: python, c++, pytorch, libtorch, torchscript

I am trying to use pytorch (.pth) model in c++. The best way I found is to convert .pth to TorchScript module. I was able to convert .pth model to TorchScript module successfully, however converted model's output is not the same as original model's. I am sure that model's inputs are the same in the both cases. Here are conversion code and inference code parts:

```
model = Model().to(device) # base pytorch model
model.load_state_dict("path/to/weights", map_location=device) 
input1 = torch.rand(1,1,32,100,dtype=torch.float32).to(device)
input2 = torch.LongTensor(1, 12).fill_(0).to(device)
traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(model,(input1,input2,)) # Convert to torchscript
traced_script_module.save("tracedModel.pt")
```

```
torch::jit::Module model; // C++ inference
model = torch::jit::load("path/to/the/traced model");
model = model.eval();
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("image/path");
torch::Tensor input1 = Processing(image); 
torch::Tensor input2 = torch::zeros({1, 12});
std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> inputs = {input1,input2};
torch::Tensor out = model.forward(inputs).toTensor();
```

```
model = Model().to(device) # Python inference
image = cv2.imread('image/path') # Same as in c++
input1 = Processing(image)  
# The Processing function has exactly the same output such as in c++.This is guaranteed.
input2 = torch.LongTensor(1, 12).fill_(0).to(device)
out = model(input1,input2)
```

Can you, please, suggest a way to solve this problem (Why models outputs are different?) or, if it is impossible, suggest another way to use .pth model in c++. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1- Have you tried using `script` instead of `trace`? If you have conditionals on your model that can make a whole difference.
2- Try loading your .pt model through python and see if you get a different result than the C++ rather than comparing to the original model